# Silverlight Defaulting ContentPresenter Content

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, default, contentpresenter

Why won't this work?

In *generic.xaml* for a custom control:

In the style applied to the custom control...

```
<Setter Property="ChromeContent">
  <Setter.Value>
    <Grid />
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

...

Later, in the control template...

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
     x:Name="ChromeContentPresenter" 
     Content="{TemplateBinding ChromeContent}" />
```

Here's the dependency property for ChromeContent...

```
public Object ChromeContent
{
  get { return (Object)GetValue(ChromeContentProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ChromeContentProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ChromeContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ChromeContent", typeof(Object), 
    typeof(casPopup), null);
```

As you can see, it takes any object.  I tried changing it to a Grid, but that did not help.

It throws this error (from javascript): _Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.Content'

Oddly, the following will work fine if I remove the Grid from the setter nd just use text:

```
<Setter Property="ChromeContent" Value="DEFAULT" />
```

Also, this will work too from the OnApplyTemplate method in the control class:

```
  Grid g = new Grid();
  g.Width = 100;
  g.Height = 25;
  g.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
  ChromeContent = g;
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what is preventing the default content of a grid, defined in the generic.xaml from working.  Does anyone have any knowledge on this matter?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:-

```
<Setter Property="ChromeContent">
  <Setter.Value>
    <Grid />
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

You should not include a `UIElement` directly in a resource dictionary or as a value of a style.  You might see the style as being some kind of descriptor but it isn't.  The values in a style are constructed instances of the objects they hold.  Your style holds a single instance of `Grid`.  Whenever that style is used to assign to a `ChromeContent` property it will attempt to assing the same **single** instance of the Grid.

A `UIElement` can only be a child of one parent.  What would happen if two instances your control were constructed?  There would (if silverlight let you) be an attempt to assign the same **single** instance of the  Grid to both controls.

This is one reason for templates such as `ControlTemplate` and `DataTemplate`.  The markup inside these is invoked each time the template is used rather than when the Xaml is first parsed.

**Edit**:

To answer you supplementary question, you should default another property of type `DataTemplate`:-

```
<Setter Property="ChromeContentTemplate">
  <Setter.Value>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Property:-

```
public Object ChromeContentTemplate
{
  get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ChromeContentTemplateProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ChromeContentTemplateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChromeContentTemplateProperty=
    DependencyProperty.Register("ChromeContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), 
    typeof(casPopup), null);
```

Control Template:-

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
     x:Name="ChromeContentPresenter" 
     Content="{TemplateBinding ChromeContent}"
     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ChromeContentTemplate" />
```

Comment: Wow, very interesting.  I did not know this.  A follow up question if I may: How would I do this with the Control Template?  When I attempt to place default markup in the ContentPresenter, I cannot add things like grids and such.  I do want the user's content to override mine if they provide it, so I'm not sure where to go from here.