# Subclass a silverlight templated control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, controls, custom-controls

I want to create few custom controls. Here is a screen shot of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Editor Screenshot]

Each control contains two parts, a label (TextBlock) and an editor (UIElement). The label part is common to all controls. I don't want to keep defining label in each custom controls I create. So I thought of creating a base class. Here is the base Editor class.

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PartLabelName, Type = typeof (TextBlock))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartEditorName, Type = typeof (ContentPresenter))]
public abstract class Editor : Control
{
    protected const string PartLabelName = "PartLabel";
    protected const string PartEditorName = "PartEditor";

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LabelStyle", typeof (Style), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(Style)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LabelHeight", typeof (double), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LabelWidth", typeof (double), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Label", typeof (string), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EditorControl", typeof (FrameworkElement), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EditorWidth", typeof (double), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EditorHeight", typeof (double), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EditorStyle", typeof (Style), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(Style)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LabelColor", typeof (Brush), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

    private ContentPresenter _partEditorControl;
    private TextBlock _partLabel;

    protected Editor()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof (Editor);
    }

    public Brush LabelColor
    {
        get { return (Brush) GetValue(LabelColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Style EditorStyle
    {
        get { return (Style) GetValue(EditorStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditorStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public double EditorHeight
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(EditorHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditorHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public double EditorWidth
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(EditorWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditorWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public Style LabelStyle
    {
        get { return (Style) GetValue(LabelStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public double LabelHeight
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(LabelHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public double LabelWidth
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(LabelWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public FrameworkElement EditorControl
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement) GetValue(EditorControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditorControlProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _partLabel = GetTemplateChild(PartLabelName) as TextBlock;
        _partEditorControl = GetTemplateChild(PartEditorName) as ContentPresenter;

        if (_partLabel == null || _partEditorControl == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Template parts are not available");
        }
    }
```

And here is the style for base editor.

```
<Style TargetType="local:Editor">
    <Setter Property="LabelWidth" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="LabelHeight" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="EditorHeight" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="EditorWidth" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="LabelColor" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Editor">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PartLabel"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                                   Width="{TemplateBinding LabelWidth}"
                                   Height="{TemplateBinding LabelHeight}"
                                   Style="{TemplateBinding LabelStyle}"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding LabelColor}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                          x:Name="PartEditor"
                                          Height="{TemplateBinding EditorHeight}"
                                          Width="{TemplateBinding EditorWidth}"
                                          Style="{TemplateBinding EditorStyle}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding EditorControl}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So I created my first custom control that extended the editor class.

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PartLabelName, Type = typeof (TextBlock))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartEditorName, Type = typeof (ContentPresenter))]
public class NumericUpDownEditor : Editor
{
    private ContentPresenter _partEditorControl;
    private TextBlock _partLabel;

    public NumericUpDownEditor()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof (NumericUpDownEditor);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _partLabel = GetTemplateChild(PartLabelName) as TextBlock;
        _partEditorControl = GetTemplateChild(PartEditorName) as ContentPresenter;

        if (_partLabel == null || _partEditorControl == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Template parts are not available");
        }
    }
}
```

And the default style

```
<Style TargetType="local:NumericUpDownEditor">
    <Setter Property="EditorControl">
        <Setter.Value>
            <toolkit:NumericUpDown />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I use this NumericEditor in a user control, nothing is displaying.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Orientation="Vertical">
    <customControls:NumericUpDownEditor Label="Numeric Up" />
</StackPanel>
```

I only want to set the editor UIElement in each custom control I create.
Do I need to define template for NumericEditor in style as well ? Or what else am I doing wrong ?

Thank You

Comment: What you asked isn't clear. Can you be more precise ? What's your problem exactly ?

Comment: I added a screenshot and extra info. Does it improve my question ?

Comment: You want to generalize a couple of `Label` + `Editable zone` in a single control ? And use this control everywhere ?

Comment: Yes exactly. So a TextBoxEditor will have a TextBox control as editor. NumericUpDownEditor will have a NumericUpDown control as editor and so on..So as you can see in my NumericUpDownEditor default style I set the editor to a numericupdown. But when I use it, nothing is displaying.

Comment: It's not a good idea because you will fall in layout issues except if you put fixed sizes on both label and control (which is a bad idea too). 
You should better create a class with both a "DataHolder" property and a "ControlKind" enum property, and put this data in an ItemPresenter's ItemsSource, and use a TemplateSelector to select the kind of control, with a Grid.SharedSize to layout this correctly.

Comment: I didn't get what you said, can you provide some sample code ? Cheers

Comment: Okay... I will put you an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake. I'd to remove default style from sub-classed control. And through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829550/silverlight-defaulting-contentpresenter-content) found out that I'd to declare the editor part control in style of the subclass inside a `ContentTemplate (DataTemplate)` rather than `Content`

Modified Editor style and class code

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorControlTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EditorControlTemplate", typeof (DataTemplate), typeof (Editor), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PartEditor"
                  Height="{TemplateBinding EditorHeight}"
                  Width="{TemplateBinding EditorWidth}"
                  Style="{TemplateBinding EditorStyle}"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding EditorControl}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding EditorControlTemplate}" />
```

Modified Subclass editor

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PartLabelName, Type = typeof (TextBlock))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartEditorName, Type = typeof (ContentPresenter))]
public class NumericUpDownEditor : Editor
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof (double), typeof (NumericUpDownEditor), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    private ContentPresenter _partEditorControl;
    private TextBlock _partLabel;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _partLabel = GetTemplateChild(PartLabelName) as TextBlock;
        _partEditorControl = GetTemplateChild(PartEditorName) as ContentPresenter;

        if (_partLabel == null || _partEditorControl == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Template parts are not available");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the style for the sub-classed control

```
<Style TargetType="local:NumericUpDownEditor">
    <Setter Property="EditorControlTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <toolkit:NumericUpDown
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:NumericUpDownEditor}, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```